# twitter bootstrap - JS not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is probably really stupid question.
I love boostrap and using it CSS styling for pretty long time, how ever when i try to use any of their JS things it's not working for me.

I always make sure I have this in my  tag but still

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It looks i am completly blind or i don't know what I am always doing wrong. Is there a chance somebody can help me with that?

Thanks.

Example code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Audatex History</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing JQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Note: Include it before the bootstrap JS.

**And you must initialize**

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
</script>
```

Note: Include it before the end tag head.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Luis P.A. but it looks i miss something more, 
http://jsfiddle.net/qott91d1/1/

Comment: Yes...you must initialize it -<script> $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
}) </script>

Comment: Thank you, it actualy work right now. May I ask if there is somewhere a list of that how I can inicializate boostrap JS things?

Comment: Yes - On this page, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ . On every link/Item there info about it

Comment: your answer is correct so i mark it :) but still will be nice if you can answer me on one more thing. 
For example there is this example about collapse:
`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">`
But it say nothing about JS

Comment: If don´t say anything it´s because don´t need to initialize it

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery. Include it before you include the bootstrap JS.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @itamar, but even if I include it before or after, same effect (not working) , look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/qott91d1/2/

Comment: I was goign to say what Luis said below - initialize the popover.